# Matching XML tags

Tags: python, xml

I'm trying to match the `name` with the `awsAccountId`. My current attempt is to save both to two separate lists then `zip` the lists to a dictionary.

The issue arises when one of these XML tags is empty, then the matching gets mixed-up. Or at least the end of the dictionary is out by one match but I'm not sure why exactly.

The XML snippet is provided below, this is just one of hundreds of iterations. Is there a better way to parse this data?

My current code:

```
def api_call():
    API call here using python requests
    return r.text

root = ET.fromstring(api_call())

name_list = []
for name in root.findall('.//AssetDataConnector/name'):
    name_list.append(name.text)

aws_id_list = []
for aws_id in root.findall('.//AssetDataConnector/awsAccountId'):
    aws_id_list.append(aws_id.text)

id_name_dict = dict(zip(aws_id_list, name_list))
print(id_name_dict)
```

XML file:

```
<data>
    <AssetDataConnector>
        <id>123456789</id>
        <name>AWS_Region_Connector</name>
        <awsAccountId>123456789</awsAccountId>
        <type>AWS</type>
        <tag>
             <id>36997499</id>
             <name>AWS_Tag_Name</name>
        </tag>
    </AssetDataConnector>
```

Comment: I'd rather iterate over `.//AssedDataConnector` and select both `name` and `awsAccountId` from each item, creating list of tuples (or dict)

Comment: Please upload a **VALID** xml

Comment: Can you edit your question and show an example with both good and problematic tags?